# Why cookie object in JSP can contain just value of type String?

Tags: java, jsp, session, cookies

As a beginner in JSP I noticed that we can hold any value inside of a *session*, while *cookie* can have value only of type String. I found it weird because what if someone wants to hold type other than String in Cookie?

- Session:

> setAttribute(String name, Object value)
>
> Binds an object to this session, using the name specified.

- Cookie:

> Cookie(String name, String value)
>
> Constructs a cookie with a specified name and value.

Can someone from community help me understand it? Why we can't store anything inside Cookie except String, while we can inside Session's labels?

Or from a different perspective, why should cookie hold only String value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a cookie is specified by [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) to store literal string values for a web browser to send as part of the HTTP request header.

From the linked RFC,

> ```
> cookie-header = "Cookie:" OWS cookie-string OWS
> cookie-string = cookie-pair *( ";" SP cookie-pair )
> ```

**tl;dr** cookie(s) are part of (and specified by) web protocols (not Java).

Comment: That is clear - API's rules. But why just String? What if I want to store List and use it as dropdown's options... or any other possible example other than that?

Comment: @Stefan First, a cookie is sent with every client request (so it should be tiny). Second, the session is typically implemented with a cookie (where it's something like `jsessionid=<long pseudorandom string>`). You should really look at the link I have provided. It goes into great detail about what a cookie actually is.